# What does it mean to check-in Code

Tags: github, version-control, continuous-integration, devops

I am new to the DevOps world and I am reading about Continuous Integration, What does it mean to `check-in` your source code. Does this mean pushing it to the branch after you write the code?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control

Comment: Yes checking in means updating your code base with the other developers and get in full sync.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Checking-in code means to upload code to main branch repository so that its administrator can review the code and finally update the project version. Additionally, checking-out code is the opposite which means to download a copy of code from the repository. 
For example, on GitHub, cloning means checking-out code and pull request means checking-in code.